# Protractor test ngFor inside accordion

Tags: angular, protractor

Am having a ul tag inside accordion. How to count the number of elements inside ul tag using protractor ? Also I need to fetch movie title inside ul tag. Can anyone suggest me how to achive this ?
Sample HTML file:

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime" [showArrows]="true">   
<accordion-group id="forth-coming" class="heading" heading="UPCOMING MOVIES" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
    <ul class="movies">
        <ul *ngFor="let movie of upcomingData">
            <div class="results">
                <!--Card content-->
                <div class=movie-card>
                    <!--Card image-->
                    <div class="movie-poster">
                        <img class="poster lazyautosizes lazyloaded" data-sizes="auto" alt="It" sizes="185px" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2{{movie.poster_path}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <p class="flex">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <a id="movie_346364" class="movie-title" href="/movie/346364" title="It" alt="It">{{movie.title}}</a>
                            <!--Rating-->
                            <span class="movie-rating">{{movie.vote_average}}
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star-rating"></span>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <!--Description-->
                        <p class="movie-description">{{movie.overview}}</p>
                        <button (click)="clickMe(movie,$event)">
                            <span *ngIf="!myRecommData[movie.title];" class="recommend">Recommend</span>
                            <span *ngIf="myRecommData[movie.title];" class="unrecommend">UnRecommend</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</accordion-group>
```

Comment: `<ul>` only makes sense if you have `<li>` children

Answer (score 0):

```
let movies = element.all(by.css('.movie-card'))
expect(movies.count()).toEqual(<expected count>)
```

Comment: It returns value as zero

Answer (score 0):

*`ngFor` is not covered by the built-in Angular-specific Protractor locators.*

You can/should go with a CSS selector, for instance:

```
var movieCards = $$("#forth-coming .movies ul");

// log to the console
movieCards.count().then(console.log);

expect(movieCards.count()).toEqual(2);
```

As far as movie titles go, you can further chain the `movieCards` to get to the titles:

```
var movieTitles = movieCards.$$(".movie-title");

// log to the console
movieTitles.getText().then(console.log);

expect(movieTitles.getText()).toEqual(["Movie Title 1", "Movie Title 2"]);
```

Comment: Am trying like return fetchCount(){ element.all(by.css('forth-coming .movies ul')) }    page.fetchCount().count()
          .then((count: number) => {
            console.log(count)
          });   But it always returns the value as zero

Comment: @mongoUser you are missing the `#` before the `forth-coming`.